# Task.Wait() on async method works locally, but not via another method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I recently resolved a problem I had while trying to execute an async method. To me, this posed more questions than it solved. In short, I am happy that it works, but I don't know why it does.

I was attempting to run the following method of the Microsoft Graph Client library:

```
_graphServiceClient.Users[userPrincipalName].Request().GetAsync()
```

The following approach did not work, as it hangs after using `await`:

```
async Task<User> GetUser(string userPrincipalName)
{
    User user = await _graphServiceClient.Users[userPrincipalName].Request().GetAsync();
    return user;
}
```

The following approach also did not work, as it hangs after executing `runTask.Wait()`:

```
User GetUser(string userPrincipalName)
{   
    return (User) GetResult(_graphServiceClient.Users[userPrincipalName].Request().GetAsync());
}

object GetResult<TResult>(Task<TResult> task)
{
    using (task)
    using (var runTask = Task.Run(async () => await task))
    {
        try
        {
            runTask.Wait();
            return runTask.Result;
        }
        catch (AggregateException e)
        {
            throw e.InnerException ?? e;
        }
    }
}
```

This is where things get weird, as the following code did work:

```
User GetUser(string userPrincipalName)
{   
    using (var task = Task.Run(async () => await _graphServiceClient.Users[userPrincipalName].Request().GetAsync()))
    {
        try
        {
            task.Wait();
            return task.Result;
        }
        catch (AggregateException e)
        {
            throw e.InnerException ?? e;
        }
    }
}
```

While I realize that the last two approaches are not considered best practice, I am completely puzzled as to why the third approach works, while the second one does not. To me, it looks like these are nearly identical.

So why would the third method work, but not the second one?

Comment: what you mean by hangs actually?

Comment: I mean that it does not continue execution, supposedly due to a deadlock. The last method returns a User within a second, while the other methods could be left in execution forever without ever returning.

Comment: Can you show place where GetUser() is called in both cases? Whole function should help

Comment: It's called from a Post() method of an ASP.NET application. So consider it being `string userPrincipalName = "test.user@intuneforeducation.com"; 
User user = GetUser(userPrincipalName);`

Comment: Reading between the lines, "hangs" almost certainly means **deadlocked**

Comment: Your second method (that doesn't work) will be trying to `await` on a different synchronisation context to that where the `Task` was created. Because the `Task` is created on the main thread but the `await` is in a `Task.Run()` thread. *I'd image* (though I'm not positive) that this is why it's deadlocked.

Comment: Your second (none working example)  should definitely not be used. It's got some tricky semantics. If for no other reason the "working" example is a lot more cleaner. Though the 100% correct approach here is `async` all the way up.

Comment: Are you sure that you await for method in your POST method in first case?

Comment: Yes your **first** one looks the most correct providing your correctly `await` it, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to understand [how the deadlock happens](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). `await` will (by default) capture a "context" and will [resume executing the rest of the `async` method in that context](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). In the ASP.NET Classic case, this "context" is a request context, *which only allows one thread to run at a time*. When running on a thread pool thread, the "context" is a thread pool context, which just queues the rest of the `async` method to the thread pool, where it can be run by any thread pool thread.

[Blocking on asynchronous code is an antipattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). In situations where you have a single-threaded context (e.g., ASP.NET Classic), you can end up in deadlock. In your first deadlocking example, you have `GetUser` called in the ASP.NET Classic context, so its `await` will capture that context. Then the calling code (also running in the ASP.NET Classic context) will block on that task. This blocks a thread in that context, which prevents `GetUser` from completing, so you end up with a deadlock.

But even if you don't end up in deadlock, you still end up throwing away all the benefits of asynchronous code in the first place. Consider the "working" example, which falls into another [antipattern (`Task.Run` on ASP.NET)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx). In this case, `Task.Run` causes `GetAsync` to run in the thread pool context, so blocking a thread in the ASP.NET Classic context doesn't deadlock. However, this is also an antipattern.

The *proper* solution is to go [`async` all the way](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). Specifically, your controller action should be `async` and use `await` when calling asynchronous code. Just pretend that `Wait()` and `Result` don't exist, and your code will be much happier.

Comment: Wow, it is an honor to have my question answered by you, mister Cleary! I stumbled onto your blog several times while researching my original problem before I came to this dirty solution. Before I did, all the methods in my Model were `async`, but my controller action was indeed synchronous and used `.Result` all the time. I suppose that would be the cause of my original problem. I'll roll it back and see if I can make it work with an `async` controller action. Thank you!

Comment: By converting my Model methods back to `async`, making the controller action `async` and avoiding `.Result`, I was able to make it all work like it is supposed to. Thanks again!